# Espresso - Assert EditText

Tags: android-studio, android-espresso, assertion

I want to check whether the text "Search YouTube" is present.

[Find the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1kA3.png)

I have tried this, but doesn't work

onView(withText("Search YouTube")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));

Comment: What's the specific error that you get?

Comment: androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "Search YouTube".   @agoff

Comment: That's probably not a text, it looks more like a hint, try `withHint("Search YouTube")`.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. This works.